# Accessing particular value of JSON object

Tags: json

I have a JSON object which I'm displaying in console and which looks like that:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"A",
      "value":"..."
   },
   {  
      "name":"B",
      "value":"..."
   },
   {  
      "name":"c",
      "value":"..."
   },
   {  
      "name":"D",
      "value":"..."
   },
   {  
      "name":"E",
      "value":"..."
   },
]
```

The thing is that I need to access only a particular value. If I want to access, for example, the value of name `C`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#find`.

```js
var data = [ { "name":"A", "value":"..." }, { "name":"B", "value":"..." }, { "name":"C", "value":"..." }, { "name":"D", "value":"..." }, { "name":"E", "value":"..." }, ],
    result = data.find(({name}) => name === 'C');
    
console.log(result);
```

```js
var data = [ { "name":"A", "value":"..." }, { "name":"B", "value":"..." }, { "name":"C", "value":"..." }, { "name":"D", "value":"..." }, { "name":"E", "value":"..." }, ],
    result = data.find(function(o) { 
      return o.name === 'C';
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: in my code itself i'm getting the error: `Shorthand property names are not supported by your current JavaScript version `

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = [  
   {  
      "name":"A",
      "value":"..."
   },
   {  
      "name":"B",
      "value":"..."
   },
   {  
      "name":"c",
      "value":"..."
   },
   {  
      "name":"D",
      "value":"..."
   },
   {  
      "name":"E",
      "value":"..."
   },
]
console.log(data.filter(function (item) { return item.name == "c" })[0].value)
```

Comment: i'm getting this error in console : `arr.filter is not a function` (in my case `arr` is the object)

Answer (score 0):

Because the language is not specified I am just giving you the basic idea of the flow.

- Get the JSONArray.
- Start a for loop for(int i=0;i

  In the loop get JSONObject by jsonarray.get(i)

  Get the string by its key; jsonobject.getString("name")
  jsonobject.getString("value")

You can get both values by the position of json object in the array.

For demo I am uploading android code for such operation

```
 JSONArray array = <your array>;
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
    JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject();
    try {
        jobj.get("name");
        jobj.get("value");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```